# Debugging ServiceStack’s react-lite and vue-lite

Tags: servicestack

How can I attach a debugger to debug the typescript part (react/vue) of the new “lite” templates?

For regular SPA projects with `npm` there are two ways I know of:

- either debug from VSCode - run SS and `npm start` and then attach to Chrome
- debug within Chrome, as the typescript source maps are available somehow

With the new “lite” templates debugging the server-side is easy, but what to do with Typescript/React/Vue debugging? I tried to run SS from command-line, and then attach VS Code to port 5000, but the breakpoints won't hit (not even for the compiled JS files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no source maps support in the [Vue/React lite Project Templates](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-lite) so you won’t be able to debug the original .ts source files and you’ll need to debug the bundled .js instead from Chrome’s WebInspector.

Comment: Any plans for source maps support? The _lite_ templates look *very* promising, but lack of easy debugging (compiled typescript inside a large bundle is not that easy) would limit it to small projects only I think.

Comment: @specimen could definitely explore if it's possible in C# but don't want to force bringing additional npm tools since it's the whole goal of the "lite" projects was that there was no complicated tools like npm or webpack. In the meantime, you can always go back to `console.log()` debugging :)